# How do I create unique log filenames using thread local in a gunicorn wsgi app?

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have a Django app with logging configured using dictConfig.

Within dictConfig I call a custom filehandler that returns an instance of FileHandler with a filename.

The filename is obtained by making an instance of thread local and giving it a uuid attribute.

The app is served via gunicorn. When I test the app making two calls via postman, logs are written to the same file.

I thought wsgi created a unique Django process for each web request, but I think it creates a process per worker that shares memory space, which I believe is why the filename remains the same after Django sets up the logger.

How do I create unique log filenames using thread local in a gunicorn wsgi app? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: "wsgi created a unique Django process for each web request" That would be terribly slow, and that's why it's not what happens. Why do you need these unique log filenames? Do you want a log file per request..?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The app is for upgrading load balancer code and generates a lot of debug logs. It was setup before to write to a single file with a request id in each log message which could be parsed, but I thought it'd be nicer to have a separate file for each upgrade run against a device as it's 1000s of devices. Request id or PID or any unique identifier for the filename is good as device ID is constant and there could be multiple upgrade attempts against the same device and I don't want to overwrite.

Comment: I think you're going to need a custom `FileHandler` subclass for this that is somehow request-aware and thus knows where to write.